# Given a one-to-many map, an algorithm that tells whether a one-to-one "subset" of the map can cover all items

Tags: algorithm, mapping, linear-algebra

I'm not sure what the proper terminology is to search by (I've searched "mapping algorithms" and "one-to-one algorithms"), and I can't think of a simpler (more canonical) formulation.

I have two sets, say

```
A B C D E
```

and

```
L M N O P
```

and I am given a one-to-many map, *e.g.*

```
A --> L, M, N, P
B --> M
C --> M, N, O
D --> N
E --> O, L
```

What's the simplest and/or fastest algorithm that tells whether a one-to-one "subset" of the map can cover all items? For example, there *does* exist such a "subset" for the above:

```
A --> P
B --> M
C --> O
D --> N
E --> L
```

I don't need to know the subset map *itself*, only *whether or not one exists*.

The "brute force" algorithm is obvious—a slight improvement is to go depth-first and backtrack whenever no item fulfills a necessary mapping—and another improvement perhaps is to go in ascending order of mappings, *e.g.* first `B --> M`, `D --> N`, then second `E --> O, L`, etc.

But all these seem like primitive variants of a brute force search. Is there a better algorithm? I have a vague memory of using linear systems to solve problems like these, like converting the map into a matrix and doing some kind of a reduction that determines an answer, but I'd have to re-learn linear algebra to figure this out—maybe SO can help me out faster.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like Bipartite max cardinality matching to me... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs Wikipedia is not a good resource on how to solve this, though.

Comment: Check out this thread on TopCoder on how to solve this: http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/;jsessionid=A62313900862E9AD237A2EDDFB40CDC4?module=Thread&threadID=684427&start=0&mc=10 My comment is only correct if the 2 sets are disjoint, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh - Thanks! Those were the words I needed, I think. I found [this paper](http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18433S07/matching-notes.pdf) that does an excellent job of introducing the problem. But I'm lost as to what the algorithm is. I see, "_Theorem 2. A matching M is maximum if and only if there are no augmenting paths with respect to M._", and "_Claim 3. There exists an augmenting path in G with respect to M i there exists a directed
path in D between an exposed vertex in A and an exposed vertex in B._", which I know must lead to the solution by contradiction, but...

Comment: If you need the problem solved, then just C/P code and plug in the numbers. I don't prevent you from reading the algorithm, but it will take time to understand it. (TBH, I don't understand the algo, but I know where and how to use it).

Comment: @nhahtdh - Would you consider posting your comments as an answer? After all, you provided the name of the problem I was looking for, and also linked to possibly the most efficient algorithm available. I've upvoted Yexo but I feel you deserve the accepted answer. (I've read your profile, which is why I'm explaining.) No problem if you disagree, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the 2 sets are completely disjoint, the problem you are solving can be reduced to [Bipartite Maximum Cardinality Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs) problem. If the maximum number of matching can be done is equal to the cardinality of the first set, then there exist a subset of the mapping that covers all items.

Apart from the conversion of Bipartite Matching problem to a flow problem, [this topic on TopCoder](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=684427&start=0&mc=10) mentions a faster way to solve the problem with Kuhn's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is "bipartite matching". The easiest way to solve this is by transforming it into a flow problem. Make one source, connect it to every element of your first set. Connect every element of the first set to one or more elements from the second set (make those connections which are in your one-to-one map). Now connect every element in the second set to a single sink. All those connections should have weight 1.

You can use any maximum flow solving algorithm (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem for ideas) to check the maximum flow. If the maximum flow is exactly equal to the number of elements in each set than there exists a mapping like you are searching for.

Comment: Transforming to flow is slower than one other way to doing it (check the TopCoder thread).

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of Kuhn's algorithm. It's indeed a bit faster. The second solution given there is the same as what I described here.